# Python3: how to fastest compute the frequency of words of in a large list, if the word of this list is or not in another large word list

Tags: list, python-3.x, word-frequency

There are two list. One list called lst1=[word1, word2, ......], the length of lst over 40000. Another list called lst2 =[word1, word2,......], the length of lst2 is about 10100. The lst2 is the feature words, I want to get the frequency of lst2 words in the lst1. For example:

```
 lst1 = ['I', 'am', 'foot', 'girl', 'mom', 'fish', 'mom, 'baby']
 lst2 = ['mom', 'baby', 'mother'].
```

So the frequency of lst2 words in lst1: is 'mom': 2, 'baby':1, 'mother':0. My code is following:

```
def pronoun_feature(lst1, lst2): 
    dict_p = {}     
    for item in lst2:         
         if item in lst1:             
            num_item = lst1.count(item)                     
            dict_p.update({item: num_item})         
         else:                 
            dict_p.update({item: 0})      
    return dict_p
```

You know the length of my two list is two large, the computing time is taken about 0.02-0.1s. Do you have more faster method to approach my result. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

The code looks like this:

```
from collections import Counter

def pronoun_feature(lst1, lst2):
    counts = Counter(lst1)
    dict_p = {}
    for item in lst2:
        dict_p[item] = counts[item]
    return dict_p
```

We won't need if/else or try/except in case of items from `lst2` not being in `lst1` here, because according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

> Counter objects have a dictionary interface except that they return a
>   zero count for missing items instead of raising a KeyError

Comment: thanks @Maurice, the speed of computing is 3 times than before.

Comment: I'm happy to help - library functions tend to be quite a lot faster than your own implementations :-)